# What to do after cloning the project from github

Tags: php, git, github, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I cloned the project from github and then when I tried to run the project this appeared on my screen as shown in image. There is no backend and frontend and I am not sure what to do next to make my clone project runable.

[image]

Comment: Clone mean it copy the code from github to your PC. After that you need to place the code in webserver or localserver and linking the project with database.

Comment: main-local.php is missing in common/config directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a console terminal, execute the init command and select dev as environment.

`/path/to/php-bin/php /path/to/yii-application/init`

or simply way if u have php configured in system environments:

`cd /path/to/yii-application`
then
 `php init`

And of course all is in docs where u can find full instructions how to exacly install Yii2 application: [Yii2 start installation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)

Comment: Thanks. i already did it by running int and then composer update in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

After Clone Checkout Branches from repository in which your running code present then pull those branches and run code again.

Comment: nothing is missing except main-local.php file in commom\config folder